# apa6 title page formatting problems

Tags: formatting, titles, apa6

So I'm using `apa6` to write in APA format for a school project, and I'm having trouble with the title page.  On sources like OWL the format for the title page looks like this:

[image: Proper Format]

However, what I get looks like this:

[image: Incorrect Format]

The problem is the new line character that appears between the title and the author's name.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\title{test}
\shorttitle{test}
\author{weirdesky}
\affiliation{University}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

I've taken a look at the documentation on `apa6`, but the formatting for the title page seemed to only be mentioned in passing, and I was unable to find any formatting options.  Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're after? The `noextraspace` removes the additional `.25in` space between the title and the author.

[image]

```
\documentclass[man,noextraspace]{apa6}
\title{Test title \par another title}
\shorttitle{test}
\author{weirdesky}
\affiliation{University}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I missed that in the documentation.  Looking at back at it, though, even if I had seen it, it probably wouldn't have occurred to me to use it.
Thank you.